# Add value in Object Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: javascript

I'm working with Angular 2 ( typescript)

I have an Object:

```
obj = {
"cadSocios" : true
};
```

And I need to add to it other values:

```
obj2 = {
"name" : ['name1', 'name2'],
part : ['part1', 'part2']
};
```

My Final Object must be:

```
objFinal = {
"cadSocios" : true,
"name" : ['name1', 'name2'],
part : ['part1', 'part2']
};
```

How can I do this? in array can use .push, and Object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign` function

```
obj = {
 "cadSocios" : true
};
obj2 = {
 "name" : ['name1', 'name2'],
 part : ['part1', 'part2']
};

merged = Object.assign(obj, obj2);
```

working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeecq5or/)

Answer (score 6):

#### Method 1.

**`Object.assign`** function, provided by ES6.

```js
var obj1 = {
"cadSocios" : true
};

var obj2 = {
"name" : ['name1', 'name2'],
part : ['part1', 'part2']
};

var obj = Object.assign(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj);
```

#### Method 2.

Simple **`for in`** loop.

```js
var obj1 = {
  "cadSocios": true
};

var obj2 = {
  "name": ['name1', 'name2'],
  part: ['part1', 'part2']
};

for (prop in obj2) {
  if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    obj1[prop] = obj2[prop];
  }
}

console.log(obj1);
```